# Magento 2.4.2 How to implemented single image upload in from the admin side using the UI component and Save and Show in product Edit/ Add Page

Tags: magento2, product-images, uicomponent, custom-options, image-upload

I am Trying to create Custom Field to upload single Image. With the help of various documentation I tried to implement using UI Component. Thanks for your help my code is given below.

app/code/PCsoft/ProductCustomField/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="PCsoft\ProductCustomField\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">label/tmp/image</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">label/image</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/PCsoft/ProductCustomField/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *
 * Created By : Rohan Hapani
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="pcsoft_productcustomfield" frontName="pcsoft_productcustomfield">
            <module name="PCsoft_ProductCustomField" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/PCsoft/ProductCustomField/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Upload.php

```
<?php
 
namespace PCsoft\ProductCustomField\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
 
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use PCsoft\ProductCustomField\Model\ImageUploader;
 
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public $imageUploader;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ImageUploader $imageUploader
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }
 
    
 
    public function execute()
    {
        $imageUploadId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name', 'image');
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageUploadId);
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

app/code/PCsoft/ProductCustomField/Model/ImageUploader.php

```
<?php
 
namespace PCsoft\ProductCustomField\Model;
 
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
 
class ImageUploader
{
    private $coreFileStorageDatabase;
    private $mediaDirectory;
    private $uploaderFactory;
    private $storeManager;
    private $logger;
    public $baseTmpPath;
    public $basePath; 
    public $allowedExtensions;
 
    public function __construct(
        Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->baseTmpPath = "label/icon";
        $this->basePath = "label/icon";
        $this->allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    }
 
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }
 
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }
 
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }
 
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }
 
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }
 
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }
 
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }
 
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();
        $baseImagePath = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);
        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }
        return $imageName;
    }
 
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
            );
        }
 
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];
        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app/code/PCsoft/ProductCustomField/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="pcsoft">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">360° Gif</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.pcsoft</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</item>
            </item>
        </argument>                
        <field name="image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Label </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select 360° Gif Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">PCsoft_ProductCustomField/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="pcsoft_productcustomfield/index/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

app/code/PCsoft/ProductCustomField/view/adminhtml/web/template/image-preview.html

```
<div class="file-uploader-summary">
    <div class="file-uploader-preview">
        <a attr="href: $parent.getFilePreview($file)" target="_blank">
            <img
                class="preview-image"
                tabindex="0"
                event="load: $parent.onPreviewLoad.bind($parent)"
                attr="
                    src: $parent.getFilePreview($file),
                    alt: $file.name">
        </a>
 
        <div class="actions">
            <button
                type="button"
                class="action-remove"
                data-role="delete-button"
                attr="title: $t('Delete image')"
                click="$parent.removeFile.bind($parent, $file)">
                <span translate="'Delete image'"/>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="file-uploader-filename" text="$file.name"/>
    <div class="file-uploader-meta">
        <text args="$file.previewWidth"/>x<text args="$file.previewHeight"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have successfully reached till here.
[image]

**What should I do for the next step ?**

Comment: Do you means you want to more than 1 upload fields?

Comment: What I want is to save the file while saving the product and show the uploaded file when the product is opened for edit.

Comment: Now, you has save the data to product and load the image data for your field.

Comment: @HoangHieu I would like to know how can I achieve that as I am new to magento and couldn't find perfect documentation to achieve as you mentioned

Comment: You can review the module magento/module-catalog, it allow upload an image to category.